# Windows 10 on Virtual Box not working

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Im trying to get windows 10 vm working in Ubuntu so that i can run adobe programs. It gets stuck everytime right here, whats up with that? Any ideas?

[Helpful picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJHcr.png)

Comment: Same as here: https://askubuntu.com/a/930371/423684 ? Only the other way round?

Comment: Mostly, a resource issue. That's one downside of using VM.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing windows 7 in OS version didn't work for me, but this does: In VM settings -> System -> Acceleration Tab -> Paravirtualization Interface -> Choose KVM instead of Default.

Answer (score 1):

Changing it from windows 10 64 bit to windows 7 64 bit ( in the OS selection, actual IOS image the same, windows 10) made it work flawlessly. Im not sure what the reason for this fixing it, but it was the solution for me.

Comment: This is an unorthodox solution for sure, but I tried it and now my Windows 10 guest starts up great.  Time will tell whether there are any negative side effects, but so far it's running great.