# Ubuntu download and install on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10

Downloaded ubuntu  16.04.2-desktop-amd64 on a Windows 10 64 bit intel i7.

Why does iso filename say amd ? 
Tried running this iso on virtualBox and got message as Kernel version is not correct. Which version do i need to download?

Answer (score 0):

amd64 is all 64-bit XX86 class processors regerdless of manufacturer.

vitrualbox is 32 bit. get the 32bit version. i386 will be at then end of the image name